# How to have multiple pods in one git repo

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, cocoapods

**Context**

We are developing a large software platform which includes Android, Server, Web and iOS (with others to come). To keep all of our code up to date with each other we keep it all in one Master repo (this is very important as we share a model across all platforms so commits can be affecting many different platforms).

To handle the iOS side we've decided to break the project down into modular pods so that we can easily share them across our other libraries (also pods), and so that when we release it is easy for our clients to include our api in their existing projects (i.e. we want to use the cocoapods structure for all of the wonderful benefits cocoapods provides).

To accomplish this I've gone about setting up a private spec repo and pod specs for each of our projects.

**tl;dr**: We've got one master git repo that holds all of our code (multiple platforms, including multiple different pods). We want to keep this structure  but also be able to create pods from the code within the repo.

**Question**

The issue I'm running into is all the documentation I can find for pod specs say you have to use this format:

`spec.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git',
                :tag => spec.version.to_s }`

the only part that trips me up is that our repo does not only contain one pod (let alone just iOS code).

Is it possible to do something like:

`spec.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/MyCompany/Master/MyCompanyCoreDir',
                :tag => spec.version.to_s }`

We really appreciate any help

Cheers

Indigo

Comment: Did you finally figure it out how to do it?

Answer (score 22):

It is possible to have multiple cocoapods on single Git repository.

Just as you said, you can specify different sources for each that lead to specific pod code.

In order for this to work, you have to also set proper **source_files** in spec, for example: `s.source_files = 'SomePodDirectory/*.swift'`.

You can even manage multiple versions of each pod by using something like this for **source**: `s.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/MyCompany/Repository.git', :tag => 'SomePodName-v'+String(s.version) }`.

In that case you should create proper tags on Git (for example `SomePodName-v1.0.0`).

Answer (score 3):

The exact term which you're looking is **subspec** in `podspec` file. Under the **subspec** in `podspec` file, mention the `source_files` directory.

Ex:

```
  # SwiftStdlib Extensions
  s.subspec 'SwiftStdlib' do |sp|
    sp.source_files  = 'Sources/Extensions/SwiftStdlib/*.swift'
  end

  # Foundation Extensions
  s.subspec 'Foundation' do |sp|
    sp.source_files  = 'Sources/Extensions/Foundation/*.swift'
  end
```

If you need more detail, just check the [SwifterSwift](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift) Podspec file.